# Labels turned dark when printing as graphics in vb 2013.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I will start this with an honest introduction.
I'm very confused with my problem that I cannot put it into words I'm really sorry if my question is not appropriate. I just can't make the words for my query. (English is not my native language)
So this is my prob,whenever I try to print my form as graphics and save it as pdf it works just fine but what's bugging me is the darker color the labels get that are off the screen, what I mean is I got a scrollable form and the darker labels that appear are the ones that are not visible by the user without scrolling the form. Here is a screenshot to redeem my self, XD

[image: Partial screen of the form, this is what the user initially sees when not scrolling the form]

Partial screen of the form, this is what the user initially sees when not scrolling the form.

This is the screen for the generated pdf file.

[image: The darker part of the screen is the lower part of the form]

There it is, as you notice the part where the screen is visible looks fine but not the lower part. I don't what caused this really as I am very new in vb development.

Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Gave Jayson +1 BACK - Dont mark down without a VALID reason and share the REASON - its NOT fair to mark down for the joy of it!. His question seems correct enough and with enough etiquette too!

Comment: Without code, we have nowhere to start trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for the defend Zaf I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Justin I already found the culprit I'll be posting the solution. You'll definitely laugh at me. Hahaha..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after fiddling with my vb project it seems that the code is correct and the culprit is with the settings of the labels. I used a transparent background for the labels which when I turned it to white the issue disappears. Well I really don't know what happened and why it was like that, but it fixed it. Hoorah! :)